# Change temporary file directory in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to use PROC.SQL statements for my analysis. The problem is, SAS uses C disk in order to create temporary files when I use SQL statements. My datasets are very large and I do not have enough space for that. Could you please explain me how to allocate this temporary file in other place rather than C disk?

Comment: It depends on what you are talking about. If you are making datasets then you can create them where you want by making a libref and using that in the dataset name. If you are talking about the utility files that SAS might create when running some complicated SQL query that requires sub queries or sorting then you probably will need change the UTILLOC option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to change the `WORK` system option.  You can do:

```
c:\sas\sas.exe -work d:\temp
```

to use the `d:\temp` directory.

You can also use the `OPTIONS` statement within the config file used when starting SAS (thanks [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4965549/tom)):

```
options work='d:\temp'
```

See also:

- [Indiana University answer for SAS on UNIX systems.](https://kb.iu.edu/d/addl)
- [SAS 9.2 documentation on system options.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#changesysopt.htm)

Comment: Thanks for answer. How to do that? Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: You can modify the shortcut you use to start SAS, or you can add the options statement to your SAS script.  Please mark this answer as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: I couldnt do that. Could you please show this as an example? So I run the codes? I need to do that before running code, am I right?

Comment: Try adding the `options` statement above to the top of your SAS script.  Make sure to change `d:\temp` to match your actual temporary drive that you plan to use.

Comment: @khaladdin please post what you're trying when you claim things don't work. We can't know if you did something wrong or the answer is wrong for some reason.

Comment: You cannot change the WORK option after SAS has already started. Either set it on command that starts SAS or in the config file used when starting SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'user' library instead. When a USER library is in effect, all one level datasets are written to this directory and it's used as the default instead of WORK library.

```
 libname user 'path to other location';
```

Comment: Maybe not a good idea unless you want the datasets saved permanently to disk.  In the OPs question he's specifically mentioning temporary storage, not permanent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently change sas work location, you can set it in sasv9.cfg. (Default location: C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\sasv9.cfg). Along with -WORK, you may also want to change the value for -UTILLOC option.

You can even spread a Load across Multiple Volumes of Different Disks. Please read Example 1 mentioned in this link - https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1qr5dmzagn9krn1lt1c276963za.htm